# How to get a SQL statement from rails ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I run `Company.where(foo: nil)` then I get a message like this:

```
  Company Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."foo" IS NULL
```

Is there a way to get this SQL statement as a return value?

Sometimes I want to know what kind of SQL statement is created from `ActiveRecord::Relation` without runnning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can add `to_sql` on the end `Company.where(foo: nil).to_sql`

here's the docs on `to-sql`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql